# Integral test in the example $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt i}$

Tags: calculus

> Check if the series are convergent:
>
> $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt i}$

After concluding $\lim\frac{1}{\sqrt i}=0$

I used the integral test: $\int_\limits{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt i}=2i^{\frac{1}{2}}|^{\infty}_1=\infty$

So the series are not convergent.

I do not have solutions and I am self-studying.

***Questions***:

Do you think my answer is right?

Shall I use the integral test every time to ratify if the series are convergent?

Comment: This is correct.  You can also compare it with the Harmonic Series, because this sum is always larger than the Harmonic Series which diverges.

Comment: Looks right to me! You should use the integral test any time that you're able to, because it's a quick way to prove convergence/divergence. However, there are many functions you can't integrate, and you'll need to try other methods. It's all about knowing the methods well and using the best one.

Comment: @HarryAlli                     Thanks for the feed back!

Comment: Am I to wrong to assert the integral test is useful only when he function is positive, decreasing and continuous?

Comment: @Kaynex               Thanks for the  feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one is knowing what the integral test says:

> Let $f:[\alpha,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ be a non-negative and monotone (weakly decreasing) function such that $\int_\alpha^x f(t)\,dt$  exists for all $x>\alpha$. Then, $$\int_\alpha^\infty f(x)\,dx<+\infty\iff \sum_{n\ge \alpha}^\infty f(n)<+\infty$$

As you see, you checked something which didn't *need* to be checked - a.k.a. $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0$ - while you *did not* check the actual hypothesis - that is, $\frac1{\sqrt x}\le\frac1{\sqrt y}$ for all $1\le y\le x$ (**in** $\Bbb R$).

So, for me the answer to the first question is **NO** (although you ended up with the correct fifty-fifty).

The answer to the second question is: do as you like. Every time a sequence $a_n$ can be written as $f(n)$ for some positive and monotone Riemann-integrable function $f$, you can use the integral test. Is it the only way to go? No. Is it always the easiest? No. For instance, in this case you could have also used Cauchy's condensation test, or direct comparison with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k$, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right. To verify click [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%E2%88%9Ax)

But

> You should use integral test only when series is monotone decreasing

Otherwise you may get wrong results. For reference click [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)